# Understanding an example of a pencil where addition is that of an elementary abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, projective-geometry, projective-space, geometric-group-theory

I'm trying to understand the Latin square in picture 2.1 of the paper "On Projective Planes of Order Nine" by Marshall Hall, Dean Swift, and Raymond Killgrove  (https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1959-13-068/S0025-5718-1959-0107208-8/S0025-5718-1959-0107208-8.pdf).  This is regarding a plane of order 9 with three pencils of finite lines x=c, y=c, and y=x+c.  "Specifically this last pencil may be represented by the Latin square:"

$\begin{matrix}0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8 \\
1&2&0&4&5&3&7&8&6 \\
2&0&1&5&3&4&8&6&7 \\
3&4&5&6&7&8&0&1&2 \\
4&5&3&7&8&6&1&2&0 \\ 
5&3&4&8&6&7&2&0&1 \\
6&7&8&0&1&2&3&4&5 \\
7&8&6&1&2&0&4&5&3 \\
8&6&7&2&0&1&5&3&4 \\ 
\end{matrix}$

The rows represent permutations of $S_9$ and are understood as lines with 9 finite points.

I can't for the life of me figure out the operation (possibly ternary) of this "elementary abelian group."  Any insights would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The [elementary abelian group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_abelian_group) for the prime power 9 is the set of $(a,b)$ tuples, where the components $a$ and $b$ are integers mod 3, and addition of tuples is done componentwise. (n.b. 9 factored is $3^2$, so we get tuples of 2 numbers, mod 3).

The table is just $x + c$, where $x$ is the column index and $c$ is the row index (though note the table is symmetric, so this convention is just to match how Hall talks later about permutations). However, each number has to be interpreted in the tuple form above by taking the trinary representation of the number, i.e.
$$0 = 00, 1 = 01, \dots 3 = 10, 4 = 11, 5 = 12, \dots 8 = 22.$$ Then the addition of the provided square is just componentwise addition of the indexes.

For example, the second row from the top is derived:

```
1 + 0 = 01 + 00 = 01 = 1
1 + 1 = 01 + 01 = 02 = 2
1 + 2 = 01 + 02 = 00 = 0
1 + 3 = 01 + 10 = 11 = 4
1 + 4 = 01 + 11 = 12 = 5
1 + 5 = 01 + 12 = 10 = 3
1 + 6 = 01 + 20 = 21 = 7
1 + 7 = 01 + 21 = 22 = 8
1 + 8 = 01 + 22 = 20 = 6
```

(See also [Wikipedia on Latin squares and quasigroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Latin_squares_and_quasigroups))